# Reducing the size/extents of a QGIS project created from geodatabase (.gdb)?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

I have imported a .gdb geodatabase into QGIS by dragging and dropping the .gdb file into QGIS layers region. The project covers a large amount of territory and there are a lot of layers.

Due to the project's extents and size, QGIS is very glitchy and slow to the point of almost being unusable.

Is there a way to zoom into a smaller region and trim/cut the project extents to this area? Perhaps exporting it to a new QGIS project file that can be worked on vs. the large project?